# Have mstest output my log file at a desired location

Tags: c#, mstest

I have test that runs in mstest, everything works fine and it gives me a log file.
But the log file is outputted in the TestResults folder in the project. Is there a setting I can change in mstest, which upon changing lets me output the log file to a location I desire.

If their is please advise me how to go about doing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per `mstest.exe /?` there is a command-line flag you can use:

```
 /resultsfile:[file name]          Save the test run results to the specified
                                   file.
                                   Example:
                                     /resultsfile:c:\temp\myresults.trx
```

Comment: I was looking more for a config setting(since i still wanted to use the visual studio ide rather than cmd line), but if no one comes up with a better answer i will mark this as accepted.